# How to display user selected image in listview

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, imagesource

I am new to using xamarin for mobile development.
I am developing a contact book project using xamarin forms. In the code shown below I am aiming to provide a listview that would be dynamically be increasing based on the number of callers provided by the user.

The **listview** is going to diplay a button that is going to fetch contact image which will be provided by user from gallery, an entry field for contact name and a circle **image** displaying user selected contact image.

I want each image in the **listview** to be based on the **image** selected by the user for that particular contact name.

Although I was successfully able to retrieve image from user. It was not being displayed.

Kindly help and let me know what I am doing wrong.

LocalContactInfo.xaml

```
    <ListView x:Name="lstView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button x:Name="pickPhoto" Text="pick photo" Clicked="Handle_Clicked"/>
                        <Entry Placeholder="name" />
                        <ic:CircleImage 
                            Source="{Binding image}"
                            WidthRequest="70"
                            HeightRequest="70"
                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                            x:Name="circleImage" />

                    </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

LocalContactInfo.xaml.cs

```
public partial class LocalContactInfo: ContentPage
{
    async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Photos Not Supported", ":( Permission not granted to photos.", "OK");
            return;
        }
        var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
        {
            PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium
        });
        if (file == null)
            return;

        var image = ImageSource.FromFile(file.Path);
        }
    int count;
    public LocalContactInfo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LocalContactInformation caller= new LocalContactInformation();
        count = Convert.ToInt32(caller.callerCount);
        BindingContext = null;
        var icon = Enumerable.Range(0, 2); //enter the number of callersin range i.e. count
        lstView.ItemsSource = icon;
        }

}
```

Comment: a. you appear to be assigning your ListView's ItemSource to an empty enumerable.  b. your Handle_Clicked creates a local image source and then does nothing with it.  It will fall out of scope as soon as your handler completes.

Comment: @Jason what should I be mentioning in ListView's ItemSource and about the image source I tried using the code 'circleImage.Source=ImageSource.FromFile(file.Path);'
but while building I am getting an error that **'the name circleImage does not exist in the current context'** As I am new to all this I am not able to understand as what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You presumably want your ListView bound to a List<LocalContactInformation>.  Xamarin has a number of excellent articles and samples on using data binding, you should really read them.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be trying to use `BindingContext` since you're setting `Source="{Binding image}"`, but the 'image' variable in your EventHandler clearly isn't bound to the cell and the ListView's `ItemsSource` is an `IEnumerable<int>` (which honestly won't work well).

If the list Cell truly has a `BindingContext` you could retrieve it in your click handler using the 'sender' parameter.

e.g. `((VisualElement)sender).BindingContext.imageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(file.Path);`

When you indicate that you're still having the problem i could set up example code for you.